# Injecting package.json version into Gitlab CI scripts

Tags: docker, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci

What is the best way to inject values from package.json (the name and version is what I am interested in) into a Gitlab CI pipeline (i.e. the .gitlab-ci.yml file)?

My current use-case is that I want to use the name and version of the project to start a SonarQube scan and I do not want to update a version in both the package.json and sonar-project.properties files.
The Sonar scan will be executed in a container with the image sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest, so the `node` and `npm` commands are not available, but I would be willing to install them, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the docker image that I was using to run the sonar scan (sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest) has the `node` executable included, which means that I can load the values using node:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').name") -Dsonar.projectVersion=$(node -p -e "require('./package.json').version") -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```